# What is the meaning of ついて in ついてしまう

Tags: meaning, verbs

I have this sentence

```
勝負はついてしまったらしい
```

I guess it comes from 付く which would be in my opinion a similar form to 付いて来る.
Is my guess OK, or is has the ついて here a different origin?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the verb is 付く【つく】, the same 付く as in 付いてくる. It has many meanings (jisho.org gives 14 definitions and [デジタル大辞泉 gives 28](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BB%98%E3%81%8F_%28%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F%29/#jn-147036)), and one of the meanings is "to be settled/determined/resolved". Similar usages include:

- 勝負がつく
- 話がつく
- けりがつく
- 目途がつく
- 決着がつく
- 区別がつく
- 決心がつく
- 気持ちの整理がつく

Unsurprisingly, the transitive equivalent つける means "to settle/determine/resolve".

- 勝負をつける
- 話をつける
- and so on

On the other hand, we do not say <sup>×</sup>結論がつく or <sup>×</sup>議論がつく. Verbs like つく, かける, とる and する have many possible meanings, and it's often more practical to remember which noun goes with which verb as a set phrase, one by one. [English also has](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/42912/8629) a large number of unpredictable verb usages. (English speakers say "do the dishes", but not "do the glasses". Japanese people never say 皿をする. This is something a learner has to remember.)