# Meaning of つき in 都合がつき次第

Tags: word-usage

Full sentence: 都合がつき次第、こちらから連絡します。

Does it simply mean "attached to" or something of that kind? Or is it some other word?

Comment: 都合がつく is a phrase. Then masu-stem + 次第 is a grammar point. Is that enough for you to figure it out?

Comment: Related [What is the meaning of ついて in ついてしまう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/74386/)

Answer (score 3):

都合がつく is a set collocation. The verb is the same as the one you know as "be attached to": 付く

I think this usage corresponds to the following definition in スーパー大辞林.

> [五] 実現・決着が望まれていたことが実現・決着する。

The dictionary lists these examples.

> やっと決心がついた。

> まだあきらめがつかない。

> ふんぎりがつかない。

> あっさり決着がついた。

> 混乱して収拾がつかない。

> あの問題はかたがついた。

> けりがつく。

> 当事者の間で話がついた。

There is also 都合をつける.